# ROS Topics not being published with Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following camera sensor added in a .world file:

```
<model name='camera'>
  <link name='link'>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.000166667</ixx>
        <iyy>0.000166667</iyy>
        <izz>0.000166667</izz>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
      </inertia>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
    </inertial>
    <sensor name='camera' type='camera'>
      <camera name='__default__'>
        <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>320</width>
          <height>240</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <visualize>1</visualize>
    </sensor>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
    <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <shader type='pixel'/>
      </material>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <transparency>0</transparency>
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
    </visual>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>1</mu>
            <mu2>1</mu2>
            <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
            <slip1>0</slip1>
            <slip2>0</slip2>
          </ode>
          <torsional>
            <coefficient>1</coefficient>
            <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
            <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
            <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
            <ode>
              <slip>0</slip>
            </ode>
          </torsional>
        </friction>
        <bounce>
          <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
          <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
        </bounce>
        <contact>
          <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
          <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
          <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
          <ode>
            <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
            <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
            <kp>1e+13</kp>
            <kd>1</kd>
            <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
            <min_depth>0</min_depth>
          </ode>
          <bullet>
            <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
            <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
            <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
            <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
            <kp>1e+13</kp>
            <kd>1</kd>
          </bullet>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <static>0</static>
  <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
  <plugin name='stereo_camera_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so'>
    <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
    <cameraName>test/camera</cameraName>
    <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
    <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
    <frameName>left_camera_optical_frame</frameName>
    <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
    <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
    <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
    <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
    <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
    <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
  </plugin>
  <pose frame=''>-22.3817 16.9364 0.05 0 -0 0</pose>
</model>
```

The simulation launches with the model, but when I look for the topic for the camera does not show up. Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365655/ros-topics-not-being-published-with-gazebo/) by [iamrandom](https://answers.ros.org/users/59093/iamrandom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-11-16**:
I don't have much experience with cameras in Gazebo, but it seems that you have a `camera` sensor defined but are trying to use the `multicamera` plugin.  Also, judging by the [Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Multicamera), the plugin element should be nested inside the sensor element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@tryan's two points are right: for a single camera you should use the `camera_controller` plugin, and you should put the `plugin` block inside the `sensor` block. Below is a complete world file with those two change that works correctly. Save it as `foo.world` and then run it as `roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch world_name:=`pwd`/foo.world`. After simulation is up, `rostopic list` includes the desired camera topics:

```
/test/camera/camera_info
/test/camera/image_raw
/test/camera/parameter_descriptions
/test/camera/parameter_updates
```

foo.world:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">
    <!-- A global light source -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <!-- A ground plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <model name='camera'>
      <link name='link'>
        <inertial>
          <mass>0.1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.000166667</ixx>
            <iyy>0.000166667</iyy>
            <izz>0.000166667</izz>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
          </inertia>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        </inertial>
        <sensor name='camera' type='camera'>
          <camera name='__default__'>
            <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
              <width>320</width>
              <height>240</height>
            </image>
            <clip>
              <near>0.1</near>
              <far>100</far>
            </clip>
          </camera>
          <always_on>1</always_on>
          <update_rate>30</update_rate>
          <visualize>1</visualize>
        <plugin name='camera_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_camera.so'>
          <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
          <cameraName>test/camera</cameraName>
          <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>left_camera_optical_frame</frameName>
          <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
          <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
          <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
          <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
          <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
          <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        </plugin>
        </sensor>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <visual name='visual'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <shader type='pixel'/>
          </material>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
          <transparency>0</transparency>
          <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
        </visual>
        <collision name='collision'>
          <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>1</mu>
                <mu2>1</mu2>
                <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
                <slip1>0</slip1>
                <slip2>0</slip2>
              </ode>
              <torsional>
                <coefficient>1</coefficient>
                <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
                <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
                <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
                <ode>
                  <slip>0</slip>
                </ode>
              </torsional>
            </friction>
            <bounce>
              <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
              <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
            </bounce>
            <contact>
              <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
              <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
              <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
              <ode>
                <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
                <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
                <kp>1e+13</kp>
                <kd>1</kd>
                <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
                <min_depth>0</min_depth>
              </ode>
              <bullet>
                <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
                <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
                <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
                <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
                <kp>1e+13</kp>
                <kd>1</kd>
              </bullet>
            </contact>
          </surface>
        </collision>
      </link>
      <static>0</static>
      <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
      <pose frame=''>-22.3817 16.9364 0.05 0 -0 0</pose>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/22196/gerkey/) with karma: 1981 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iamrandom](https://answers.ros.org/users/59093/iamrandom/) on 2020-12-30**:
This worked! Thanks to @tryan as well for the comment.